# Combinar valores de arrays y sumar 2 valores del mismo PHP

Tags: php, array, funciones, matriz, matrices-asociativas

Buenas estoy intentando almacenar toda mi información de ventas en un array, pero no encuentro la manera de juntar todos los índices de un array en unos solo y que éste sume los valores de 2 de sus elementos

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_despacho] => 9
            [id_producto] => 4
            [Categoria] => 15
            [TipoDespacho] => Financiamiento
            [Producto] => CONCORD SACO 25 KG
            [cantidad] => 52
            [unidades] => KG
            [precio] => 35.45
            [total_venta] => 1843.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_despacho] => 10
            [id_producto] => 4
            [Categoria] => 15
            [TipoDespacho] => Financiamiento
            [Producto] => CONCORD SACO 25 KG
            [cantidad] => 52
            [unidades] => KG
            [precio] => 35.45
            [total_venta] => 1843.4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_despacho] => 21
            [id_producto] => 4
            [Categoria] => 15
            [TipoDespacho] => Financiamiento
            [Producto] => CONCORD SACO 25 KG
            [cantidad] => 10
            [unidades] => KG
            [precio] => 35.45
            [total_venta] => 354.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_despacho] => 22
            [id_producto] => 4
            [Categoria] => 15
            [TipoDespacho] => Financiamiento
            [Producto] => CONCORD SACO 25 KG
            [cantidad] => 8
            [unidades] => KG
            [precio] => 35.45
            [total_venta] => 283.6
        )

)
```

Y quisiera juntar todos en unos solo pero con la diferencia de que se sumen los valores dentro de los índices `[cantidad]` y `[total_venta]` quedando así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_despacho] => 9
            [id_producto] => 4
            [Categoria] => 15
            [TipoDespacho] => Financiamiento
            [Producto] => CONCORD SACO 25 KG
            [cantidad] => 122
            [unidades] => KG
            [precio] => 35.45
            [total_venta] => 4324.9
        )
)
```

Intenté utilizar un codigo que encontré en internet, pero solo me suma el valor o de `[cantidad]` o de `[total_venta]` según se lo indique pero yo necesito que se sumen ambos

```
$sum = array_reduce($almacenarArrayVentas[15]['Financiamiento']['CONCORD SACO 25 KG'], function ($a, $b) {

       isset($a[$b['id_producto']]) ? $a[$b['id_producto']]['cantidad'] += $b['cantidad'] : $a[$b['id_producto']] = $b;  

       return $a;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado, la solución a tu problema puede ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
//Array en cuestion
$arr = array(
    array(
        "id_despacho" => "9",
        "id_producto" => "4",
        "Categoria" => "15",
        "TipoDespacho" => "Financiamiento",
        "Producto" => "CONCORD SACO 25 KG",
        "cantidad" => "52",
        "unidades" => "KG",
        "precio" => "35.45",
        "total_venta" => "1843.4"
    ),
    array(
        "id_despacho" => "10",
        "id_producto" => "4",
        "Categoria" => "15",
        "TipoDespacho" => "Financiamiento",
        "Producto" => "CONCORD SACO 25 KG",
        "cantidad" => "52",
        "unidades" => "KG",
        "precio" => "35.45",
        "total_venta" => "1843.4"
    ),
    array(
        "id_despacho" => "21",
        "id_producto" => "4",
        "Categoria" => "15",
        "TipoDespacho" => "Financiamiento",
        "Producto" => "CONCORD SACO 25 KG",
        "cantidad" => "10",
        "unidades" => "KG",
        "precio" => "35.45",
        "total_venta" => "354.5"
    ),
    array(
        "id_despacho" => "22",
        "id_producto" => "4",
        "Categoria" => "15",
        "TipoDespacho" => "Financiamiento",
        "Producto" => "CONCORD SACO 25 KG",
        "cantidad" => "8",
        "unidades" => "KG",
        "precio" => "35.45",
        "total_venta" => "283.6"
    )
);

$totalCantidad = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'cantidad')); //obtengo todos los valores de cantidad y los sumo
$totalVenta = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'total_venta')); //obtengo todos los valores de venta y los sumo


//Construyo un nuevo array
$newArr = array(
    "id_producto" => $arr[0]["id_producto"],
    "Categoria" => $arr[0]["Categoria"],
    "TipoDespacho" => $arr[0]["TipoDespacho"],
    "Producto" => $arr[0]["Producto"],
    "cantidad" => $totalCantidad,
    "unidades" => $arr[0]["unidades"],
    "precio" => $arr[0]["precio"],
    "total_venta" => $totalVenta
);

echo print_r($newArr);
```

Utilizamos la función `array_column` para obtener un array con todos los valores almacenados en las keys `cantidad` y `total_venta`. Luego con la función `array_sum` realiza la suma interna de todos los valores dentro de los array obtenidos. Teniendo todo lo anterior podemos construir nuestro array esperado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionando a la perfección